# angular checkbox save just the ones which have changed

Tags: angular

I have a list of checkboxes built using:

```
        <div *ngFor="let rule of rules">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rule.isActive" name="{{rule.ruleId}}" id="{{rule.ruleId}}" class="form-check-input">
        <label class="form-check-label"> {{rule.description}} - {{rule.message}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

All of this in within the below form:

```
<form #ruleForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateRule(ruleForm.value)" novalidate>
```

in the updateRule method is there anyway to know which of the checkboxes has changed?  I have to do a save, but rather than save them all I want to save just the ones which have changed.

Comment: can you post the sample data for rules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can track the checked rule id's You can do it the following way :

**component.html**

```
  <div *ngFor="let rule of rules">
     <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="onCheck($event,rule.ruleId)" [checked]="rule.isActive"  value="{{rule.ruleId}}" name="{{rule.ruleId}}" id="{{rule.ruleId}}" class="form-check-input">
     <label class="form-check-label"> {{rule.description}} - {{rule.message}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
activeRulesIds= []; // declare and initialize'

...........
...........
...........

onCheck(event, $value) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.activeRulesIds.push($value);
    }
    else {
      this.activeRulesIds.splice(this.activeRulesIds.indexOf($value), 1);
    }
 }
```

Comment: This code only push in activeRulesIds the rules checked, not the rules changed. I think that use an auxiliar variable, [checked] and (change) is a poor use of Angular. Of course that the code works, but,personally, I preffer a "more Angular answer"

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new property to your "rule" (e.g. you can call the "changed") and split [(ngModel)] in [ngModel] and (ngModelChange)

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="rule.isActive" 
  (ngModelChange)="rule.changed=true;rule.isActive=$event">
```

After, only send the rules that rule.changed==true

```
  const send=rules.filter(x=>x.changed);
```